# Hive throws error after sqooping data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop, parquet

I want to import data from database to HDFS in a parquet format then populate the hive table. I can't use  `sqoop import --hive-import` because sqoop moves data from the `--target-dir` to the hive metastore dir.
So, I am obliged to create the hive schema `sqoop create-hive-table`, convert the hive table to parquet `SET FILEFORMAT parquet`, change the location of hive table to point to the suitable file in HDFS and finally import data to the table using `sqoop import --as-parquet-file`

I am faced to a problem in hive : I cannot preview the data of my table because of this error :

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot inspect org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
```

1) How can I solve this problem ?

2) Is there a better solution to do this use case ?

Answer (score 0):

What is your hive version? If your version is **1.0.0**, it's a bug. Please follow this [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10086)

This bug is fixed in **hive 1.2.0** version

Comment: I am using hive-1.1.0-cdh5.9.1